# How do you cope with nausea in FPS?

Tags: first-person-shooter, health

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prevent Gaming Sickness?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/902/how-can-i-prevent-gaming-sickness)

I find that in some of the first person shooters (HL2, Doom3), I get extremely nauseated. How do you guys cope with it? or is it just me?