# What is visual strobing and how can I reduce it?

Tags: terminology, health

In the question "[How can I prevent Gaming Sickness?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/902/how-can-i-prevent-gaming-sickness)", the answer given by GalacticCowboy suggests reducing "visual strobing" as well as increasing framerate. I get how to increase the framerate in games, but I would like to know what settings I should look for in order to change the "strobing", since in none of the games I play can I find a setting that uses that word.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe he is just referring to the general effect of strobing in video games. Read more about it here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strobe_effect

I would take a look at the lighting settings in your games and possibly disabling them.

This is also a pretty good guide:

http://pixelsmashers.com/?p=4391

Comment: Yeah, apart from lighting settings you want as high a framerate as possible.  Other than that you can't prevent a game from containing flashing signs or whatever else that's been put in.  Also a minor note on the article: Benadryl requires a prescription in the US? Crazy.

Comment: @Matthew I'm not sure where the author of that article got that idea.  Benadryl is readily available over the counter in the US.

Comment: You can minimize the affect flashing lights from a video game can have on you by making sure you are playing in a well lit area as well, so there is not as much difference between the light thrown off by the monitor and the rest of the room you are in. ie: Do not play in a dark room, or even a darkened room.

Comment: @James absolutely. Playing in a well-lit room and at an adequate distance from the TV does wonders.

Comment: @Beofett, the author was probably confusing it with drugs containing  [pseudoephedrine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoephedrine).