# Why do I get sick when I'm lost (in a game)?

Tags: first-person-shooter, health

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prevent Gaming Sickness?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/902/how-can-i-prevent-gaming-sickness)

(I'm not sure if this is where I should ask this but it's related to gaming so...)

This usually happens when I'm playing a FPS but it can happen in any game (just happened to me while playing Arkham City (third person view)).  If I get lost, and I don't know where I'm going, I start to physically get ill.  I get sick to my stomach and if I keep playing, I'll get to the point where I have to lay down and close my eyes or I'll throw up.

I always considered it some form of motion sickness.  But it only happens when I'm lost.  I don't get it.

Thoughts?

Comment: We are not doctors.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the anxiety related to being lost with no idea of where to go? That said though, it's more health related than gaming.

Comment: I'm no doctor, but I did stay at a Holiday Inn last night.. To me, it sounds like a combination of motion sickness from the FPS which can happen to people, and feeling mentally disoriented by being lost in the game. (Sort of what Stephen said).

Comment: related question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/902/8366

Comment: This is closed as off topic but I'm directed to a similar question that was not closed as off topic?  Nice, gang.

Comment: @pcg79 you're right there, it's now turned into a duplicate of that one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've experienced this and in my case I believe it's because when I'm lost I'll start to run around the map (using the run function if there is one) looking for something familiar or some enemy I haven't killed.

All this running means a lot of turning around and thus a lot of visual input.  The result is a motion-sickness like feeling.

Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Too bad this question was closed as off-topic because a) it isn't and b) I think you're right. The other day when I was trying to find out where I needed to go in Uncharted 3 (before I cranked up the brightness) I started feeling ill from staring at the rapidly moving walls and floors. +1

Comment: @JamesSkemp This question has been re-closed as a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/902/how-can-i-prevent-gaming-sickness, which has some other tips as well

Comment: Huh. Didn't even know this had been re-opened. It looks like I upvoted at least one of the answers to that question, so I'm guessing I read Dave's comment to the original post and headed over there.